# proliferation of rocket tray icons

Tags: testdriven.net

Each time I run a test using TestDriven, it creates another "rocket" icon on my system tray.  I have to manually do right-click Quit to get rid of them.  How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Check for any open file handles you may be creating in your tests. Depending on the size of your test suite that may be too time consuming and tedious. There's an option to turn off caching the test process between test runs in the options for TestDriven.Net. This seems to be designed for instances like what you're seeing. From their documentation:

> **Cache test process between test runs**
>   *By default the external test process will be cached when the ‘Run Test(s)’ command is used. This process appears in the tool tray as a rocket icon which can be used to kill the process. This is fine unless one of your tests starts leaking leaking native resources (such as leaving open a file handle). The best solution is to fix the resource leak, but you now have to option to work around the issue by killing the test process at the end of each test run. This can be useful if the resource leak is in a 3rd party DLL which can’t be easily be changed.*

From here: http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2008/12/03/testdriven-net-options-pane.aspx

I realize you asked this a year ago, so you may have already figured out a way to fix the problem. In that case, I would ask that you let us know what you did.